# How to select max of two columns and group it by station on MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a simple table like this

```
 station    num     tim
 -------------------------
   1       150       10
   1       200      222
   1       100     5000
   1       200      555
   2       100      500
   2       120      200
   3         1        2
```

The desired output is like this:

```
station  num     tim
---------------------
   1     200     555
   2     120     200
   3       1       2
```

but I can't use `ROW_NUMBER()` because query needs to be executed in MS Access SQL.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using subquery

```
select A.* from
(
select station,num, max(tim) as mtim
from tablename
group by  station,num
)A where num in (select max(num) from tablename B where A.station=B.station)
```

Comment: return error 'Circular refrence caused by alias 'tim' in query definitions SELECT list'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
select t2.station,t1.num as num,max(t2.tim) tim from (select max(num) num  
from tablename group by station) t1
join tablename on t1.num = t2.num group by t1.num,t2.station
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two `exists` queries:

```
select s.*
from simple as s
where s.num = (select max(s2.num)
               from simple as s2
               where s2.station = s.station
              ) and
      s.tim = (select max(s2.tim)
               from simple as s2
               where s2.station = s.station and s2.num = s.num
              ) ;
```

Because this doesn't do aggregation (overall) and can make use of an index on `(station, num, tim)`, it is probably the best performing approach.